# PY selenium unittest- clicking element does not login

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, python-unittest

Want to be able to test login in a functional test with selenium.

views.py:

```
def login_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('remember_me', None):
            request.session.set_expiry(0)
    return auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

functional_tests.py:

```
class SomeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

   def test1(self):     
        self.browser.get("http://www.asite.com/account/login/")
        username = self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_username")
        password = self.browser.find_element_by_id("id_password")
        username.send_keys(USER['username'])
        password.send_keys(USER['password'])
        self.browser.find_element_by_name("login").click()

        # should now be on the right page
        self.browser.get('http://www.asite.com/loggedin_only')
        logout_link_text = self.browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,"Logout")
        self.assertisNotNone(logout_link_text)
```

Fails.
Manually it logs in and redirects to the loggedin_only page properly.
Have also tried an implicit wait.

Is there a good way of testing the redirect?

Comment: Quick check. What if you add `time.sleep(5)` after clicking the `login` button - does it make the test pass? (don't forget to `import time`)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not filling the right fields. The correct ones are in a frame. Here is an example to login to the website:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

browser.get("https://www.asite.com/login-home/")

# click login
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#top-login").click()

# switch to the login frame
browser.switch_to_frame("iFrameAsite")

# wait for the submit button to appear
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn-submit")))

# fill the form and submit
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name$='login']").send_keys('my login')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name$='password']").send_keys('my password')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input.btn-submit").click()
```